# Why is my fibonacci function using a javascript while loop not working?

Tags: javascript

Why is my code to generate a fibonacci sequence not working? Fibonacci sequence would go like this: [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34] when n=10 and so on if greater, where the last two numbers are added to give the next number. I tried this using a while loop as I initially tried using a for loop but I couldn't determine a change to put in the (). I don't think there are any problems in the first 8 lines of the code as I tried them before and they worked so problem is after but I can't figure it out...thanks in advance!

```
var seq = [];

function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

    if (n === 1) {
      seq.push(0);

    } else if (n === 2) {
      seq.push(0, 1);

    } else if (n > 2) {
      seq.push(0, 1);

      while(len < n) {
 var len = seq.length;
        seq.push(seq[len] + seq[len - 1]);
      }  
    }

  return seq;
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(10));
```

Edit: This is the code that works for n=1 and n=2 hence I'm convinced that the problem is in the while loop but I can't figure it out. :

```
var seq = [];

function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

if (n === 1) {
  seq.push(0);

} else if (n === 2) {
  seq.push(0, 1);

}
return seq;
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(2));
```

Now my console is printing [0,1]

Edit:

Ok guys I fixed the code myself and now it works if anyone wants to know how to use while loop for fib seq here it is:

```
var seq = [];

function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

if (n === 1) {
seq.push(0);

} else if (n === 2) {
seq.push(0, 1);

} else if (n > 2) {
seq.push(0, 1);

var len = seq.length;

while (len < n) {
  seq.push(seq[len-1] + seq[len - 2]);
  len++;
}
}

return seq;
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(10));
```

Comment: While should be lowercase. And you are missing a `}`

Comment: @Andreas sorry, i wanted to format the code, i changed it to `While` now

Comment: Add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem and contains an explanation for your assumption that it _"doesn't work"_ and also any error messages from the console.

Comment: Ok I have edited and added the code that works and the error message

Comment: `len` never changes, so `len < n` is always false. It looks like you're assuming len with increase as seq.length grows

Comment: Alright I have moved  
    var len =  seq.length;
into the while loop and now it's printing [0,1]

Comment: @Jacob even after moving it into the while loop?

Comment: Javascript arrays are zero based. First element has index 0 and last element has index len-1. So instead of len and len-1 you should use len-1 and len-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I fixed the code myself and now it works if anyone wants to know how to use while loop for fib seq here it is:

```
var seq = [];

function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

if (n === 1) {
seq.push(0);

} else if (n === 2) {
seq.push(0, 1);

} else if (n > 2) {
seq.push(0, 1);

var len = seq.length;

while (len < n) {
seq.push(seq[len-1] + seq[len - 2]);
len++;
}
}

return seq;
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper fibonacci module:

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n){
  var fib = []; // Initialize array!
  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    // Next fibonacci number = previous + one before previous
    // Translated to JavaScript:
    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
  }
  return fib;
}
console.log(fibonacciGenerator(10))
```

Hope it will help!

**Edit** as pinted out my function was doing adding 1 extra line. Fixed by replaceing `for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {` with `for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {`

Comment: Thank youu, actually that code was printing 1 extra item in the array but I fixed it by removing the = in line 5 so it's :

function fibonacciGenerator(n){
  var fib = []; // Initialize array!
  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    // Next fibonacci number = previous + one before previous
    // Translated to JavaScript:
    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
  }
  return fib;
}
console.log(fibonacciGenerator(10))

But it doesn't work for n=1 but anyway that can be fixed by adding a few more lines. But I still don't know why my original won't work

Comment: @argonx if my answer is correct don't forget to accept it!